# How to add more than 20 bannedAreas in HERE Maps iOS routing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api

I am testing adding in a set of bannedAreas to my route through the HERE iOS SDK. (I'm using the `iOS` Premium SDK). I have noticed however, that after 20 AddBannedArea calls, all additional information is thrown away. Is there a hard limit on the amount of banned areas? If so, how would I go about adding more in?

Here is the testing code snippet I used. At 19, the last geopolygon is still recognized and avoided while routing. If however I bump up the loop to 20, the last geopolygon , and all subsequent geopolygons are ignored.

```
NMADynamicPenalty *penalty = [[NMADynamicPenalty alloc] init];
for (int w = 0; w < 19; w++){
      float latitude = 29 + (w / 5) + (arc4random_uniform(100) / 100.0);
      float longitude = -66 - w - (arc4random_uniform(100) / 100.0);
      NMAGeoCoordinates *topRight = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
      NMAGeoCoordinates *topLeft = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:(longitude - 0.25)];
      NMAGeoCoordinates *bottomRight = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:(latitude - 0.25) longitude:longitude];
      NMAGeoCoordinates *bottomLeft = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:(latitude - 0.25) longitude:(longitude - 0.25)];
      NMAGeoPolygon *polygon = [[NMAGeoPolygon alloc] init];
      [polygon addPoint:topRight];
      [polygon addPoint:topLeft];
      [polygon addPoint:bottomLeft];
      [polygon addPoint: bottomRight];
      NMAMapPolygon *mapPolyGon = [[NMAMapPolygon alloc] initWithPolygon:polygon];
      [penalty addBannedArea:mapPolyGon];
    }
    NMAGeoCoordinates *topRight = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:40.147209 longitude:-74.648863];
    NMAGeoCoordinates *topLeft = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:40.145059 longitude:-74.726632];
    NMAGeoCoordinates *bottomRight = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:40.074601 longitude:-74.649898];
    NMAGeoCoordinates *bottomLeft = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:40.079852 longitude:-74.735551];
    NMAGeoPolygon *polygon = [[NMAGeoPolygon alloc] init];
    [polygon addPoint:topRight];
    [polygon addPoint:topLeft];
    [polygon addPoint:bottomLeft];
    [polygon addPoint: bottomRight];
    NMAMapPolygon *mapPolyGon = [[NMAMapPolygon alloc] initWithPolygon:polygon];
    [penalty addBannedArea:mapPolyGon];
```

EDIT: MORE INFORMATION

I am routing from Dover DE (lat: 39.1582, long:-75.5244) to New York City (lat: 40.7128, long: 74.0060).

I have set 19 random banned areas, and one test ban area with a box composed of

```
    NMAGeoCoordinates *topRight = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:40.147209 longitude:-74.648863];
    NMAGeoCoordinates *topLeft = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:40.145059 longitude:-74.726632];
    NMAGeoCoordinates *bottomRight = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:40.074601 longitude:-74.649898];
    NMAGeoCoordinates *bottomLeft = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:40.079852 longitude:-74.735551];
```

This box creates and area north of Mansfield TWP on I-97.

If under 20, then I get the correct dodge of this.

[image: Under 20 bannedAreas]

However, over 20, so setting the loop to 21+, and the point is completely ignored, resulting in this.

[image: Over 20]

Comment: Can you please add more information such as start and destination points/addresses and any other info to help reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added more info to the question. I used both car routing and no options, and truck routing with the same results.

Comment: Thanks for the update, we are taking a look. Will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK doesn't support more than 20 banned areas in a route request. Documentation will be updated in the next release.